# R cannot be resolved-android

Tags: android

R cannot be resolved
R.layout.main cannot be resolved
error is repeating to me and i cant run any of my android program

pls give any instruction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

also probably delete this line which sometimes creeps up :

`import android.R` or something like that.

Comment: this is not a permanent solution, you must have to clean and build again.

Comment: yeah i did but the problem is  still continuing

Comment: thank you now no error but while running time the following error is coming "An internal error occurred during: "Launching New_configuration".
Path for project must have only one segment."

Comment: @ezil: Go to Run>>Run configurations... and find "New_configuration" and delete this and run  again.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Eclipse?
Try project -> clean

Otherwise: check your console in the bottom for errors that need fixing before your R is build

Comment: s am using eclipse but still it is continuing may i want to refresh the install package

Comment: If a restart, clean and things like that do not work, you must check the errors and fix them. What errors do you have _apart_ from the R related ones?

Comment: thank you but now while run time " 'Launching New_configuration' has encountered a problem. An internal error occurred during: "Launching New_configuration" error message is coming

Comment: “please enter a name and project for your run configuration”.

Comment: http://androblip.huiges.nl/2011/02/20/eclipseavd-path-for-project-must-have-only-one-segment/

Answer (score 1):

I just had a reoccurence of the dreaded "R cannot be resolved" error, and I went through all the usual fixes; make sure all resources have lower case names, do a clean, make sure there isn't an `import android.R` lurking somewhere... no luck.

After a couple of frustrating hours I realised I had saved a PaintShop Pro format file (something.psp) in a resource folder in the file system and Eclipse was pulling it into my `res` folder. Not being a .png, it choked, and that seemed to cause the problem. As soon as I removed the .psp the error disappeared.

Hope this helps prevent someone else pulling out their hair.